# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and i'm trying to follow the instructions in this book..http://amzn.to/4nck80 and i just can't get it to work!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" ></LinearLayout>



    <TextView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="@string/hello" />



    <TextView

         android:layout_width="fill_parent"

         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:text="This is my first android application!" />

    <Button

         android:layout_width="fill_parent"

         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />



</Button>LinearLayout>
```

i'm getting the Error

> The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

by the first Textview
and a warning

> Unexpected text found in layout file: "LinearLayout>"

by `</Button>LinearLayout>`

Comment: Delete the XML and start over if you're using the GUI designer. All of your widgets should be before the </LinearLayout> XML tag

Comment: You should read a bit of [XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp) and its [syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) to start working with Android layouts because that kind of application resources are created with basic XML.I'm saying this because this is not an Android question since you say you're getting the error _The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed._ and you also have got those syntax problems that Mike Christensen told you.

Comment: Okay ill go read up a bit on XML's.. this is my first attempt at programming anything i wasn't really sure where to even start so just got the first android developer book i found heh

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors with this XML file.

First, you have an invalid XML tag.

Change:

```
</Button>LinearLayout>
```

to:

```
</Button></LinearLayout>
```

You'll also need to remove the closing `</LinearLayout>` from above, since you probably didn't mean to end the root element there.

Lastly, remove the:

```
</Button>
```

Since the button element ends with `/>` and is thus already closed.

**Final Working Version**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="This is my first android application!" />

    <Button
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried what you said and i get Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello'). activity_fullscreen.xml /HelloWorld/res/layout line 7 Android AAPT Problem and [I18N] Hardcoded string "And this is a clickable button!", should use @string resource activity_fullscreen.xml /HelloWorld/res/layout line 20 Android Lint Problem

Answer (score 0):

the linearlayout tag in the middle is unnecessary.
You should create an id for each view element you create. The ids allow you to call the elements in your mainactivity java class. Heres how to make ids:

```
<Button
android:id = "@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
Etc.........
/>

<TextView
android:id = "@+id/mytextview"
Etc......
/>
```

Fix the last line's LinearLayout tag as the person above suggested.

Yolo cash swag monday